# How to remove "authenticated-user" from this [user:roles:join-path]/[user:name]

Tags: tokens, users

I have these roles:

- anonymous user,
- authenticated user,
- administrator,
- members,
- partners.

In URL Aliases I changed at USER PATHS with this: [user:roles:join-path]/[user:name]

I created 2 views for user: first for members role and second for partners role (the views contain userpicture and username). The link for these users in both roles are :

- www.example.com/authenticated-user/members/username
- www.example.com/authenticated-user/partner/username

I know that authenticated user role is default for authenticated users, but it is possible to remove from USER PATH: from „www.example.com/authenticated-user/members/username” to „www.example.com/members/username”?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement [hook_pathauto_alias_alter()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/hook_pathauto_alias_alter/7), which is invoked from [pathauto_create_alias()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/pathauto_create_alias/7). The function passes the pattern used from the Pathauto module before the tokens are replaced in `$context['pattern']`. You probably want to check the pattern contains `"[user:roles:join-path]"` to avoid `"authenticated-user"` is removed where the pattern explicitly uses `"authenticated-user"`.

The alternatives would be:

- Implement [hook_tokens_alter()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/hook_tokens_alter/7) to alter the output of that token, but that would change it in any place the token is used, not only in alias created from the Pathauto module
- Implement [hook_tokens()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/hook_tokens/7), and [hook_token_info()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/hook_token_info/7) to implement a token similar to `[user:roles]` but that doesn't include the string for the authenticated user role

Notice that it is the Pathauto module that handles the :join-path part of the token, in [pathauto_tokens()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/pathauto_tokens/7).

Answer (score 0):

If Pathauto doesn't let you to specify a single role, I think you should create a little module that makes the same thing of pathauto but add only your favorite roles.

Pathauto has also some api and hooks, try to search there.